# Xamarin studio IOS automatic provisioning

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, licencias

oigan estoy tratando de testear un app que desarrollé en **X.F.** pero me encuentro con lo siguiente. No sé si saben para testar apps para **IOS** es un embrollo, entonces estoy tratando de correr mi app en xamararin sin licensia de apple , tengo entendido que es posible, pero tengo un problema, no puedo usar **provisioning porfile** esto lo generas cuando te registras como apple developer y pagas la licencia, pero tengo entendido que hay una forma de hacer estas pruebas sin este archvio. Ahí esta mi problema, en la parte de **teams** no me aparece nada, alguien sabe de donde salen o cómo puedo generar un team?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en la página de apple se generan esos datos

Comment: te amo pero necesito algo más conciso

Comment: como broma ya estuvo xD!!!! cheka bro:  https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership

Comment: si ya había leido de esa liga, pero como tengo una cuenta sin pago , no puedo accesar, tu sabes del tema @fredyfx o sabrías de alguien qu epueda guarme un poco?

Comment: vas a tener que invertir en tu cuenta como desarrollador :)

Comment: pues si es el plan , pero quiero tratar de hacer esto correr sin una cuenta

Answer (score 1):

Para probar la aplicación en el simulador de iOS no hace falta provisionar la aplicación usando certificado.

Para probarla en un dispositivo físico, sí que hace falta, pero puedes utilizar el aprovisionamiento gratuito, que no sirve para subir a la tienda, pero sí para probar en dispositivos, aquí está la documentación:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning